# Aligning the corrupted data records in a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

My data file(.txt) has records of  31 fields/columns each  and the fields are pipe delimited. Somehow, few records are corrupted(the record is split into multiple lines).

Can anyone guide in writing a script that reads this input data file and shapes it into a file containing exactly 31 fields in each record?

PS: I am new to powershell.

### Sample data:

Good data - Whole record shows up in a single line.

Bad data - Record is broken into multiple lines.

Below is the structure of the record.

```
11/16/2007||0007327|       3904|1000|M1||CCM|12/31/2009|000|East 89th Street|01CM1|    11073|DONALD INC|001|Project 077|14481623.8100|0.0000|1.00000|1|EA|September 2007 Invoice|Project 027||000000000000|1330|11/16/2007|X||11/29/2007|2144.57
```

Here is what i have tried and script hangs

```
#Setup paths 
$Input = "Path\Input.txt" 
$Output = "Path\Output.txt" 
#Create empty variables to set types 
$Record="" 
$Collection = @() 
#Loop through text file 
gc Path\Input.txt | %{ 
    $Record = "$Record$_" 
    If($Record -Match "(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}(?:\|.*?){31})(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\|.*?\|.*)"){ 
        $Collection+=$Matches[1] 
        $Record=$Matches[2]  
    } 
} 
#Add last record to the collection 
$Collection+=$Record $Collection | Out-File $Output
```

Comment: Please give example of both 1) what the corruption is like (missing fields? records split across multiple lines?) **and** 2) what you have tried to resolve the issue on your own.

Comment: This seems familiar. Did you try to save the result of an SQL query in SSMS to CSV? Linebreaks in one of the fields would break the csv-file.

Comment: @FrodeF. No, I am just dealing with .txt files.

Comment: the line `$Record=$Matches[2]` doesnt appear to be doing anything. You will overwrite its contents when the loop restarts with `"$Record$_"`

Comment: This part of your regex appears to be an issue (i might be wrong). `(?:\|.*?){31}` i read this as your looking for a `|` followed by 0 or more ungreedy characters 31 times. Is it possible you mean `(?:\|).{31}`. What are you trying to accomplish there. http://regex101.com/r/qY1jZ7/1 is a good resource for testing your regex strings. It would appear you have unnessacary backslashes as well

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues that need to be clarified or addressed. First I noticed the line `$Record=$Matches[2]` does not appear to serve a purpose. Second your regex string appears to have some flaws which you were looking for. When i test your regex against your test data here: http://regex101.com/r/yA9tZ1/1

At least on that site the forward slashes needed to be escaped. Once I escaped the tester threw the error at me

`Your expression took too long to evaluate.`

I know the root of that issue comes from this portion of your regex which is trying to match your passive group with a non greedy quantifier 31 times. `(?:\|.*?){31}`

So taking a guess as to your true intention I have the following regex string

```
(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}.{31}).*?(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}\|.*?\|.*)
```

You can see the results here: http://regex101.com/r/qY1jZ7/2

While i doubt it is exactly what you wanted I hope this leads you in the right direction.

Comment: That code he's running is [an answer I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813476/removing-unnecessary-line-breaks-in-a-file-using-powershell) to a very similar issue last week. The `$Record=$Matches[2]` does serve the purpose of resetting a $Record to the beginning of a new record once a finds the whole previous record. That question only had 11 fields to a record though, which probably worked better in general for the repeating passive group.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the RegEx I provided will decidedly *not* work against the sample data given. It shouldn't, it's not designed to. What it *is* designed to do is find and split two conjoined records. To see that it is valid remove the second capturing group (what would be the beginning of a second record). Or paste the sample twice with no line break. Then it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @themadTechnician for pointing out the significance of $record

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this, and while that solution worked for an extremely similar issue where the user only had 11 fields per record, apparently it's just no good for your 31 field records. I'd like to suggest an alternative using `-Split` alongside a couple of regex matches. This should work faster for you I think.

```
#Create regex objects to match against
[RegEx]$Regex = "(.*?)(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})$"
[RegEx]$Regex2 = "(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.*)"

#Setup paths 
$Input = "Path\Input.txt" 
$Output = "Path\Output.txt" 

#Create empty variables to set types 
$Record="" 
$Collection = @() 

#Loop through text file 
gc $Input | %{ 

    If($_ -match "^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" -and $record.split("|").count -eq 31){$collection+=$record;$record=$_}
    else{
        $record="$record$_"
        if($record.split("|").count -gt 31){
            $collection+=$regex.matches(($record.split("|")[0..30]) -join "|").groups[1].value
            $record=$regex2.matches(($record.split("|")[30..($record.split("|").count)]) -join "|").groups[1].value
        }
    }
}

#Add last record to the collection 
$collection+=$record

#Output everything to a file
$collection|out-file $Output
```